# php: how to communicate with a background running PHP script?

Tags: php, sockets, communication

theres a normal script running in the browser, and another in background (in a command line window, infinite). Until now, I simply used socket communication to send message to background php script and gets answer. Is there more elegant (and faster) way? I dont want to use files or database for that.

Comment: What solution did you chose? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use semaphores and shared memory to "communicate" between processes.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php

While you can do this is PHP, and I have, it's certainly not a strong point of PHP and is usually an indication you should be looking at other languages and/or solutions.

Comment: The System V IPC based communication is not available on Windows. http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend to use http://nodejs.org/ to create a server/client application or to use http://redis.io/ to manage messages between the applications.

Comment: -1 as asking about PHP, not NodeJS, and specifically asking not to use databases...